# Word counter getting negative value in C

Tags: c, char, cpu-word, counter

I am trying to develop this word counter (along with line and char counters as well). The rules are that everything is a word except anything separated by spaces, tabs, new lines, semicolons and hyphens. For example:
 'xyz' 'go;down' 'hey..howareyou' are all 1 word each and 'hey:you' 'tacos-burrito' are each 2 words.

My approach is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int charHolder, result, wordCount, lineCount = 0;

    int recursiveSeparatorCheck(charOther){
        if(isspace(charOther)||charOther=='\t'||charOther=='\n' || charOther ==':' || charOther == '-')
            return 1;
        return 0; 
    }


    while ((charHolder = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(charHolder == '\n')
            lineCount++;
        result++;
        if(recursiveSeparatorCheck(charHolder) == 1)
            continue;
        wordCount++;


    }


    printf("Number of char: %d \n", result);
    printf("Number of lines: %d \n", lineCount);
    printf("Number of words: %d \n", wordCount);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When I run my program and feed it to read a file that has 20 lines and 160 words, it prints the following:

```
Number of char: 1130 
Number of lines: 20 
Number of words: -4195164
```

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You forgot to initialize all variables but `lineCount`.  Running your program through Valgrind can help you find such bugs.  Also, you need to `#include <ctype.h>`.  Finally, `int recursiveSeparatorCheck(charOther)` should be `int recursiveSeparatorCheck(int charOther)`.

Comment: Just a note, but you can replace your whole long if clause with `strchr(" \t\n:-", charOther) != NULL`.

Comment: if the code had listed only one variable declaration per line then this problem would never have happened.  This goes to the idea that 'just because a particular code sequence can be written/complied does not mean it should be used.  It also is a prime example of why all local variables should be initialized in the declaration

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are under the impression that this line initialises all four variables to `0`:

```
int charHolder, result, wordCount, lineCount = 0;
```

It doesn't. Only `lineCount` is initialised, the rest have undefined values. Add `= 0` after `wordCount` and `result` to initialise them.

Answer (score 2):

`wordCount` is uninitialized, an it contains indeterminate value, you need to explicitly initialize it to `0`, as well as all other variables

```
int charHolder, result, wordCount, lineCount = 0;
```

is only initializing `lineCount`, for it to work you need something like this

```
int charHolder, result, wordCount, lineCount;
charHolder = result = wordCount = lineCount = 0;
```

which I don't like at all, but it seems that this is what you meant.

**Note**: You **really** need to use compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
int charHolder = 0, result = 0, wordCount = 0, lineCount = 0;
```